# how to get variable value from a java thread

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a thread which computes something and generates a 2 d array. I need to access the value of this 2 d array, when the thread is finished. How can I do that

```
        SwingWorker<Integer, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Integer, Void>()
        {
            Object[][] valueMatrix = null;

            @Override
            public Integer doInBackground()
            {
                try
                {
                    valueMatrix = doChemicalSynonyms(termsArray_1, termsArray_2, mView.getSaveFilepath(), false, mView.getSheetName(), mView.getCategoryName(), mView.includePMIDs());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void done()
            {
                System.out.println(valueMatrix[0][0]);
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
```

doChemicalSynonyms functions generates the valueMatrix. How can I access it once the thread is complete, from the main class( something like global variable)

Comment: depends on where the worker is implemented. if its the same class you could actually make it a member variable.

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). There are a few ways to do it. You could call `get()` after being notified of the `DONE` property change.

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: There is an example in the reference documentation of `SwingWorker` class, and some others in the Swing tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

what you should do is to use the `done()` method to collect any result from the thread. Basically where you are now printing the first value, you can transfer it to another thread to use it there.

Beware that the `done()` is invoked in the EDT, so if you need to do an intensive operariton on it, another thread is necessary.